# Shortcut command for docker-compose build + down + up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I found myself doing these three operations over and over again when  modifying running Docker containers:

1. `docker-compose build`
2. `docker-compose down`
3. `docker-compose up`

Is there a command in docker-compose that would do exactly these three things?

Of course a simple workaround would be to write a short shell script to the above. However, I guess that a shortcut command for the above would be very useful not only for me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The closest I can think of is this command:

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate
```

In my opinion, wrapping docker-compose in a shell script isn't a bad approach, but shouldn't be necessary in the situation you are describing.

Comment: Hi, this is great - it does what I asked for. I would usually also add a `-d` flag to daemonize the container.